# Lightning:recordForm 's onSuccess doesn't return record ID

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-record-form

I am using the lightning:recordForm for creating the record

```
 <lightning:recordForm aura:id="recordViewForm"
                              objectApiName="{!v.sObjectName}"
                              columns="2"
                              recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                              layoutType ="Full"
                              mode="edit"
                              onsuccess="{!c.onSuccess}"
                              onsubmit="{!c.onSubmit}"
                              onload="{!c.onLoad}"
                              onerror="{!c.onError}"/> 


onSuccess : function(component, event, helper) {

   console.log('event response==='+ (event.getParams("response")).Id);
   // this log statement returns --> event response===undefined

}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How to get Created Record ID in Lightning:recordEditForm?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/207165/how-to-get-created-record-id-in-lightningrecordeditform)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Seems the approach to retrieve the response is incorrectly mentioned in the documentation. Updated the usage based on a quick test.

---

This is from the documentation for [`lightning:recordForm`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordForm/documentation):

> For information about Event Return Parameters and examples of event handlers, see the documentation for [`lightning:recordEditForm`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/documentation).

And based on the documentation for `lightning:recordEditForm`, the response is returned as JSON, so to get the `Id` of the record, you will need to change your function as below:

```
onSuccess : function(component, event, helper) {
    // as mentioned in the documentation as of today, the one below does not work
    // var responseJSON = event.getParams().response;

    // based on a quick test, this works
    var responseJSON = event.getParams();
    var recordId = responseJSON.id;    
}
```

On a side not, I see you have specified `recordId="{!v.recordId}"`, which is not required to be passed if you are using this for a create scenario.

Comment: In this case, there would not be any recordId hence this will be used as create form. In edit scenario a recordId would exist and it would load the edit form for the user to create. That’s why I have used recordId in this component.

Comment: I just wanted to highlight as it seemed unusual for a create scenario but as long as you have handled it, works fine.

Comment: I get the same error as "undefined" :(

Comment: @SFDC_BigDog I updated my answer based on a quick test. That should work. Seems it's incorrectly mentioned in the docs.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Jayant